# How do I select this pivot query by specified Month

Tags: mariadb-10.1

I need help with my mysql pivot code. 
Everytime I add `WHERE MONTH(attendance_date) = 2` inside @sql_dynamic gets error. 
pls help

I have a code:

```
SET @sql_dynamic:= (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('if(sum(if(attendance_date = "',
                    date_format(attendance_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                    '",1,0))=0,0,attendance_status) AS `',
                    date_format(attendance_date, '%M-%d'),'`'
                    )
                ) from attendance
              );

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT studentidnumber, student_fullname, subject_id, ', 
    @sql_dynamic, ' 
FROM attendance
WHERE subject_id=1

GROUP BY studentidnumber'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

Comment: Please add the error message. And I cannot see `WHERE MONTH(attendance_date) = 2` in your dynamic query, please add the code that generates the error.

Comment: i finally got the correct answer. its just that the phpmyadmin cannot parse the query. i made it through mysql command line. and its working